# How to inform Google that a site is back up

Tags: google

A site I developed a year ago was ranking very well in Google for certain keywords. The domain name expired and no one noticed for about a week.

It is fixed now, but the site is no longer in any Google searches. How can I tell Google the site is back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Try filing a re-inclusion request in Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35843)

Answer (score 2):

www.google.com/WebMaster

You can request for site inclusion and removal there.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution would be to resubmit your XML sitemap (or build one if you don't already have a sitemap). You can also increase your crawl rate in GWT which will get Google to find your pages quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If owner hasn't changed midway through, I think there's a good chance it will bounce back. Register it in Google Webmaster Tools. Add some fresh links to it etc. It will probably take some days or weeks though.